# How can i draw a line surrounding all the polygons in a single layer in GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools

I have written some code in Java using the GeoTools (v.22) library that opens a shapefile, takes all the polygons in it and divides them in different FeatureCollections based on a value associated to each; 
it then creates a layer for every FeatureCollection and adds it to a map, resulting in all the polygons each divided from the others by a black stroke.

how can i draw another colored line surrounding all the polygons in the same layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Concave Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your features. So first you need to get a `GeometryCollection` of your features. You can then call Eric Grosso's [Concave Hull implementation](http://www.rotefabrik.free.fr/concave_hull/).

So something like:

```
    File f = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp");
    FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(f);

    Filter filter = ECQL.toFilter("strEndsWith(\"STATE_NAME\",'a')=true");
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(filter);
    ArrayList<Geometry> geoms = new ArrayList<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator it = collection.features()) {
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = it.next();
        Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

        geoms.add(geom);
      }
    }
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    GeometryCollection gc = gf.createGeometryCollection(geoms.toArray(new Geometry[] {}));
    gc = (GeometryCollection) Densifier.densify(gc, 5);
    double threshold = 10;
    ConcaveHull ch = new ConcaveHull(gc, threshold);
    Geometry concaveHull = ch.getConcaveHull();
    System.out.println(gc);
    System.out.println(concaveHull);
```

Which in this case generates the following map:

[image]

while a threshold of 1 gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was looking for!